# Needing some help with mac mail

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

What does All Mail mean in mac mail? I accidentally erased a mail and then did a search for it and it came up under All mail?

Comment: Is the message still in the Trash (in Mail)?

Answer (score 2):

"All Mail" in apple mail basically is just what it sounds like: a catch-all for everything on your e-mail account. I believe it does include your trash, but not your spam folder. That might be why it included an "erased" message.

Answer (score 2):

This is a setting under Mail's preferences, under the first pane, General:

"When searching all mailboxes, include results from:
         ▢ Trash
         ▢ Junk
         ▢ Encrypted Messages "

Tip: Spotlight makes a hell of a lot faster and cooler messages search than that little box in Mail and its wretched chiclets. You can even get real selective and, in Spotlight's Privacy tab, navigate your way into ~/Library/Mail/V2/email address folder to choose mailboxes to exclude.

But the way you can slide down the list of Spotlight results and see previews of each email - wowser. Apple keeps its best features secret.